# VMware VCloud REST API is not Working for deallocate public IPs from an edge gateway network

Tags: vmware, iaas, vcloud-director-rest-api

We are trying to call the following REST API to deallocate public IPs from an edge gateway network.

PUT: https://myvcloud.com/api/admin/edgeGateway/{Id of the edge gateway}/action/manageExternalIpAddresses

Request Header:

Authorization: Basic YWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvckBTeXN0AA06SW5kYXBlbmRlbnQxMiM=
Accept: application/*+xml;version=5.7
x-vcloud-authorization: 38fe9e559ad04ecf88d81f00954ce805

Request Body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ExternalIpAddressActionList xmlns="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/networkservice/1.0"><Deallocation><ExternalIpAddress>[Already Assigned Public IP]</ExternalIpAddress></Deallocation></ExternalIpAddressActionList>
```

When we are executing the above API it showing error code 404 (Resource No Found').

As per the below document I found this API is resent from version 5.7.
https://pubs.vmware.com/vca/index.jsp#com.vmware.vcloud.api.reference.doc_90/doc/operations/PUT-GetVdcTemplates.html

Team, Can you please help me out on this. Why this behavior I am getting ? Is there any alternate way available to achieve the goal.

Regards,
Sougata Halder

Comment: Greetings @Sougata, I work on vCD and this API endpoint is not implemented - thus it will always return a 404. We had mistakenly left some stubs in place which resulted in this endpoint (as well as `admin/edgeGateway/{id}/externalIpUsage`) erroneously getting documented.  This should be corrected in our next version (planned for release later this year).

Comment: So is there any direct API available to remove a public IP from an edge gateway?

Comment: I believe you'll need to do a `PUT` on the gateway and set the `vcloud:IpRanges` to the desired range(s), see http://pubs.vmware.com/vcd-820/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vcloud.api.reference.doc_27_0%2Fdoc%2Foperations%2FPUT-EdgeGateway.html